# 緯度経度を正規表現でチェックする方法（php preg_match）

Tags: php, 正規表現

緯度経度のバリデーションに正規表現を使おうと思っています。
また、前提条件としてはphpのpreg_matchを使用します。

条件が
1. 値が-180から180の範囲である。
2．実数部は6桁まで
3．ゼロ埋めは許容

ご教授ください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6桁という条件が微妙ですが、

```
OK: 180 180.000 180.00 180.0 090.000 009.000
NG: 180.001  90.0000 0.11111 0.
```

と解釈しました。

```
/\A-?(180(\.0{1,3})?|(1[0-7]\d|0?\d{2}|0?0?\d)(\.\d{1,3})?)\z/
```

こうでしょうか。(テストしてません)

非常にわかりにくいので、

- 正規表現ではフォーマットのチェック
- 範囲内かどうかは数値に変換して比較

にした方がよいでしょう

Comment: 表現がわかりづらくすいませんでした。たしかに正規表現ですべてチェックしようとするとわかりにくいですね。ご回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

[preg_replace_callback()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) を使う方法も考えられます。具体的には、`preg_replace_callback()` の callback function 内で `preg_match()` を使用します。

以下のコードでは、callback function は boolean value を返していますが、これは自動的に文字列(string type)に変換されます(`true`=>`"1"`, `false`=>`""` へ変換)。

```
<?php

$long_lat_values = [
  '',           // ng(empty string)
  '0',          // ok
  '0.0',        // ok
  '012.3',      // ok
  '124.456',    // ok
  '-45.2',      // ok
  '240',        // ng
  '-360.02',    // ng
  '10.123456',  // ok
  '10.1234567'  // ng
];

foreach ($long_lat_values as $v) {
  $result = preg_replace_callback('/^.+$/',
    function($m) {
      if (preg_match('/^[-+]?\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,6})?$/', $m[0], $match)) {
        $n = floatval($match[0]);
        return (-180.0 <= $n && $n <= 180.0) ? true : false;
      }
      return false;
    }, $v);

  printf("%10s is %s\n", $v, ($result ? 'ok' : 'ng'));
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。preg_replace_calllbackを使用してのチェックは自分では思いつけませんでした。勉強になります。

Answer (score 0):

**【回答】**

> 1. 値が-180から180の範囲である。

を正規表現でチェックするのは無理そうです。

`2.`と`3`ならば以下でよいと思います。

```
/\A[-]?[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,6}\z/u
```

※ 整数部3桁、小数点以下桁数6桁

**【確認方法】**

動作の確認は以下のツールで行いました。
[PHP: preg_match() / JavaScript: match() 正規表現チェッカー ver3.1](http://okumocchi.jp/php/re.php)

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。動作確認までしていただきありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。